# UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1417884933-3641 (-2142224028)

Tags: community, metadata-api, gack

I get this error id (1417884933-3641 (-2142224028)) when i try to use the Metadata API(.Net) to create a custom object with fields

This is my sample code

```
         CustomObject co = new CustomObject();
         co.deploymentStatus = DeploymentStatus.Deployed;
         co.deploymentStatusSpecified = true;
         co.enableActivities = true;
         co.description = objectName;
         co.fullName = "TestObj__c"
         co.label = "TestObj";
         co.pluralLabel = "TestObjs";
         co.sharingModel = SharingModel.ReadWrite;
         co.sharingModelSpecified = true;

         CustomField nameField = new CustomField();
         nameField.fullName = "TestObj Name"
         nameField.type = FieldType.Text;
         nameField.typeSpecified = true;
         nameField.label = "Name Field"
         co.nameField = nameField;

         CustomField customField1 = new CustomField();
         customField1.fullName = "TestObj__c.TestField__c";
         customField1.type = FieldType.Text;
         customField1.typeSpecified = true;
         customField1.label = "Test Field";
         co.fields = new CustomField[] {  customField1 };

         SaveResult[] results = ms.createMetadata(new metaforce.Metadata[] { co });
```

It throws the exception at the createmetadata call

EDIT:-
If i don't specify the custom field name as "TestObj__c.TestField__c" but do something like

```
customField1.fullName = "Test Field";
```

i don't get any exception and the custom object "TestObj" is created but there are no custom fields in the object

Comment: Do you have any other more descriptive error in your results list? I don't think anyone apart from Salesforce support will be able to help you resolve this problem based on what you've provided. See if you have anything in `results.errors[0].message`

Comment: i don't get back the results object because the code throws at the createMetadata call....i have also posted on the salesforce dev community forum but posted here hoping that someone might be able to figure out mistakes in my sample code.

Comment: Can you please add your API call in a try/catch block and debug the message? `try { SaveResult[] results = ms.createMetadata(new metaforce.Metadata[] { co }); } catch (Exception e) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message); }`

Comment: i did debug the exception...it's the same exact error message as the title of this question....and there is nothing else that is useful in the exception

Comment: if u or anyone u know has access to the salesforce instance in which you are trying to create the object, then please enable & monitor the debug logs for the api account and see whats happening in salesforce side.

Comment: i don't have access to do that but i have asked for adding me to the monitored users list. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I reckon the issue is at `nameField.fullName = "TestObj Name"`. Can you try changing that to `TestObj__c.Name` ?

Comment: thanks , i tried you suggestion but it didn't work....i am following the metadata reference (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm) which states  "nf.setLabel(co.getFullName() + " Name");" , so i guess the named field fullname shouldn't cause this exception.

Comment: Only 2 options - debug logs within salesforce or reach out to SF support directly. Good luck

Comment: I think you need `customField1.fullName = "TestField__c";` and *not* `customField1.fullName = "TestObj__c.TestField__c";`

Comment: As the edit in the question mentions ,  If i use "TestField__c"  , the object gets added just fine but no fields are created except from the name field. The convention ""TestObj__c.TestField__c" is what salesforce asks to do . From http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/index.htm   "You must specify the full name whenever you create or update a field. For example, a custom field on a custom object:

MyCustomObject__c.MyCustomField__c"

Comment: The edit on the question mentions "Test Field", not "TestField__c". Anyway, it does seem that the full form <objectname>.<fieldname> is required as in your main code example. Just a thought - have you tried to create an object first and then add a field in a separate transaction? Also, if you have not seen it yet, then this may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21882296/add-a-custom-field-to-an-existing-object-in-salesforce-org-using-java

Answer (score 3):

whenever we get an error of this kind(with Error ID), the exception is caught by Salesforce across the Error ID. So for speedy resolution and understanding the exact issue, its a good practice to get in touch with SFDC Support and then move forward.

Comment: yeah i already did that..i just posted here hoping i might get lucky

Comment: The error numbers aren't like Microsoft error numbers. They represent numerical entries in an internal logging system. The actual cause isn't exposed to outsiders.

Comment: Salesforce.com calls these "GACKS". Here is their writeup on it. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

And finally solved it out !

If you miss the field length it won't work, look at this:

`metaforce.CustomField nf = new metaforce.CustomField() 
nf.label = "Name Test";
nf.fullName = "Name Field";
nf.type = daTest.metaforce.FieldType.Text;
nf.typeSpecified = true;`

co.nameField = nf;

`metaforce.CustomField myfield = new metaforce.CustomField();
myfield.label = "CustomField";
myfield.fullName = "CustomField__c";
myfield.type = daTest.metaforce.FieldType.Text;
myfield.length = 30;
myfield.lengthSpecified = true;
myfield.typeSpecified = true;`

metaforce.CustomField myfieldb = new metaforce.CustomField();
myfieldb.label = "CustomFieldb";
myfieldb.fullName = "CustomFieldb__c";
myfieldb.type = daTest.metaforce.FieldType.Text;
myfieldb.length = 30;
myfieldb.lengthSpecified = true;
myfieldb.typeSpecified = true;

metaforce.CustomField myfieldc = new metaforce.CustomField();
myfieldc.label = "from_ui";
myfieldc.fullName = "from_ui__c";
myfieldc.type = daTest.metaforce.FieldType.Text;
myfieldc.length = 30;
myfieldc.lengthSpecified = true;
myfieldc.typeSpecified = true;
myfieldc.required = false;

co.fields = new metaforce.CustomField[] { myfield, myfieldb, myfieldc } ;

That works for me !

Answer (score 0):

If you r creating field along with Object then FullName of custom field should not contain "Custom object Name"

```
 customField1.fullName = "TestField__c";
```

If you create only field then only u need to write like this

```
customField1.fullName = "TestObj__c.TestField__c";
```

..

```
CustomObject co = new CustomObject();
             co.deploymentStatus = "Deployed";
             co.deploymentStatusSpecified = true;
             co.enableActivities = true;
             co.description = "objectName";
             co.fullName = "TestObj__c"
             co.label = "TestObj";
             co.pluralLabel = "TestObjs";
             co.sharingModel = "ReadWrite";
             co.sharingModelSpecified = true;

             CustomField nameField = new CustomField();
             nameField.type = 'CustomField';
             nameField.type_x = FieldType.Text;
             nameField.label = "Name Field"
             co.nameField = nameField;

             CustomField customField1 = new CustomField();
             customField1.fullName = "TestField__c";
             customField1.type = 'CustomField';
             customField1.type_x = FieldType.Text;
             customField1.typeSpecified = true;
             customField1.label = "Test Field";
             co.fields = new CustomField[] {  customField1 };

             SaveResult[] results = ms.createMetadata(new metaforce.Metadata[] { co });
```

I think this might be usefull for you if i am wrong then correct me.

Comment: i already tried this a while back....i don't get an exception but the custom field "TestField__c" doesn't get added to the custom object "TestObj__c"

Comment: Its my mistake now please check above code

Comment: what's type_x? i only see customfield.type ...